# Faster way to write this loop in MATLAB?

Tags: performance, matlab, loops

Is there a way to do this faster? I need to run this computation around a million times. Further the matrix B is of size 20x150x250.

Given a vector `dummy_t` of size `1xsize_w`, scalar m, scalar `k,d` and a matrix `A` of same size as B. For `w` such that `dummy_t(w)` is less than `m`, I compute this quantity. Else the quantity remains the same.

```
  for w=1:size_w
        if dummy_t(w) <= m
            B(dummy_t(w),w,k) = B(dummy_t(w),w,k) - d*A(dummy_t(w),w,k) ;
        end  
  end
```

Comment: Shouldn’t that be `if dummy_t(w) <= m`?

Comment: What is `cprime`? Please read [mre], then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: `B(dummy_t,w,k) = B(dummy_t,w,k)-d*A(dummy_t,w,k).*(dummy_t<=m)`

Comment: @David you probably mean this instead: 
B(dummy_t(w),w,k) = B(dummy_t,w,k)-d*A(dummy_t(w),w,k).*(dummy_t(w)<=m) ?

Comment: No but I should have had `:` instead of the `w`'s.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB has a data type `logical array`, which means a boolean array. So we can first check all elements in `dummy_t` using `dummy_t<=m`. Then use the logical indexing, get all the elements of 'True' in the logical array.

Then use this as the index to calculate.

```
dtleq3logi = dummy_t<=m; % this is a logical array
w = 1:size_w;
dtleq3 = dummy_t(dtleq3logi);
wdtleq3 = w(dtleq3logi);
B(dtleq3,wdtleq3,k) = B(dtleq3,wdtleq3,k) - d*A(dtleq3,wdtleq3,k);
```